# Отображение <div>'ов в одну строчку

Tags: html, img, выравнивание

У меня есть картинка с функцией `area` и текст. Нужно, чтобы содержимое шло в одну строку (использовал `display: inline-block;`), но получается, что выравнивание происходит по тексту, а изображения ставятся на разном уровне
(скрин прилагается).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать, чтобы выравнивание было по картинкам, а текст шёл вниз?

```html
<body>
  <div style="display: inline-block;">
    <img id="img" src="folder.svg" width="100" height="100" usemap="#Navigation" align="top" />
    <p id="txt">Текст1</p>
  </div>
  <map name="Navigation">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0, 0, 100, 100" href="uroki/test.html" />
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
      <img id="img1" src="folder.svg" width="100" height="100" usemap="#Navigation1" align="top" />
      <p id="txt1">Текст2</p>
    </div>
    <map name="Navigation1">
      <area shape="rect" coords="0, 0, 100, 100" href="uroki/form.html" />
      <div style="display: inline-block;">
        <img id="img2" src="folder.svg" width="100" height="100" usemap="#Navigation2" align="top" />
        <p id="txt2">Текст
          <br>номер
          <br>3</p>
      </div>
      <map name="Navigation2">
        <area shape="rect" coords="0, 0, 100, 100" href="uroki/form.html" />
        <div style="display: inline-block;">
          <img id="img3" src="folder.svg" width="100" height="100" usemap="#Navigation3" align="bottom" />
          <p id="txt3">Текст
            <br>номер
            <br>4</p>
        </div>
        <map name="Navigation3">
          <area shape="rect" coords="0, 0, 100, 100" href="uroki/form.html" />
          <div style="display: inline-block;">
            <img id="img4" src="folder.svg" width="100" height="100" usemap="#Navigation4" align="bottom" />
            <p id="txt4">Текст
              <br>номер
              <br>5</p>
          </div>
          <map name="Navigation4">
            <area shape="rect" coords="0, 0, 100, 100" href="uroki/form.html" />
            <div style="display: inline-block;">
              <img id="img5" src="folder.svg" width="100" height="100" usemap="#Navigation5" align="bottom" />
              <p id="txt5">Текст
                <br>номер
                <br>6</p>
            </div>
            <map name="Navigation5">
              <area shape="rect" coords="0, 0, 100, 100" href="uroki/form.html" />
              <div style="display: inline-block;">
                <img id="img6" src="folder.svg" width="100" height="100" usemap="#Navigation6" align="bottom" />
                <p id="txt6">Текст 7</p>
              </div>
              <map name="Navigation6">
                <area shape="rect" coords="0, 0, 100, 100" href="uroki/form.html" />
</body>
```

Comment: Добавьте стиль __vertical-align: top;__  вашим div'ам

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему можно решить несколькими способами.

1. Добавить `float: left;` всем div'am
2. Добавить `display: block; float: left;` всем map'aм
3. Обернуть всё это в отдельный div, а всем map'ам назначить следующие стили:

   ```
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
   ```
4. (Мой любимый) Использовать flexbox'ы. Обернуть всё в отдельный div и назначить ему следующие стили:

   ```
   display: flex;
   align-items: middle;
   ```

И да, Вам правильно указали на незакрытые парные map-теги

Answer (score 2):

Добавление **vertical-align: top;** для `div` решает проблему (в примере сохранена оригинальная верстка):

```html
<body>
  <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
    <img id="img" src="folder.svg" width="100" height="100" usemap="#Navigation" align="top" />
    <p id="txt">Текст1</p>
  </div>
  <map name="Navigation">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0, 0, 100, 100" href="uroki/test.html" />
    <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
      <img id="img1" src="folder.svg" width="100" height="100" usemap="#Navigation1" align="top" />
      <p id="txt1">Текст2</p>
    </div>
    <map name="Navigation1">
      <area shape="rect" coords="0, 0, 100, 100" href="uroki/form.html" />
      <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
        <img id="img2" src="folder.svg" width="100" height="100" usemap="#Navigation2" align="top" />
        <p id="txt2">Текст
          <br>номер
          <br>3</p>
      </div>
      <map name="Navigation2">
        <area shape="rect" coords="0, 0, 100, 100" href="uroki/form.html" />
        <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
          <img id="img3" src="folder.svg" width="100" height="100" usemap="#Navigation3" align="bottom" />
          <p id="txt3">Текст
            <br>номер
            <br>4</p>
        </div>
        <map name="Navigation3">
          <area shape="rect" coords="0, 0, 100, 100" href="uroki/form.html" />
          <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
            <img id="img4" src="folder.svg" width="100" height="100" usemap="#Navigation4" align="bottom" />
            <p id="txt4">Текст
              <br>номер
              <br>5</p>
          </div>
          <map name="Navigation4">
            <area shape="rect" coords="0, 0, 100, 100" href="uroki/form.html" />
            <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
              <img id="img5" src="folder.svg" width="100" height="100" usemap="#Navigation5" align="bottom" />
              <p id="txt5">Текст
                <br>номер
                <br>6</p>
            </div>
            <map name="Navigation5">
              <area shape="rect" coords="0, 0, 100, 100" href="uroki/form.html" />
              <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
                <img id="img6" src="folder.svg" width="100" height="100" usemap="#Navigation6" align="bottom" />
                <p id="txt6">Текст 7</p>
              </div>
              <map name="Navigation6">
                <area shape="rect" coords="0, 0, 100, 100" href="uroki/form.html" />
</body>
```